# mysql : Return rows which matches the value in array

Tags: mysql, sql

### Updated Question : I have the below data ,When i query for column consists "999" ,  I need to get last row details. Can you please guide me on this.

find_in_set not working for the array data like below. 
find_in_set("999" , column)

Table :
[image]

How do i get the last column when i query for column = 999
Dont want to use LIKE here , because I need to match for exact values

Comment: Have you tried removing the the square braces [ and ] from the column before you do find_in_set("999", column)?

Comment: i dont want to modify the data in database. do you mean after fetching the data to remove braces?

Comment: Yes also you need to remove " from the column values, it should be just 12345,999. This can be done in the query level , you don't need modify the data in table

Comment: You seemed very confused about SQL.  Can you update your question to show us an exact sample of data you want to match along with which of those rows should appear in the output?

Comment: @dishanm find_in_set just gives you the position of the string you are searching for. My answer below is based on what you have asked.

Comment: @sujith Right Thank you !!. So my data in column has ["123456","999"]  , how do I make to 12345,999 in query level. Can you please point/guide me on this !!

Comment: Are those literal double quotes or just string markers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a SQLFiddle to write and refine your query. Here is the working sample of the same:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc3f4/4

It is just a sample, which has same data as you have in your table. Modify and play with it.

Comment: Update the Fiddle link in my answer... You can see what you want. Also please mark as answer if it was helpful to you